# PHP Shopping Cart Script - When to empty cart?

Tags: php, paypal, shopping-cart, checkout

Im working on a shopping cart script in php and need some advice on how to handle the final process.

Once the customer has entered items into the cart, chosen shipping option, and then clicked the checkout button, they are then redirected to a paypal button which is dynamically generated using BMCreateButton.

My question is, when is the best time to empty the customers cart?

I have set up the auto return feature on paypal, which i was goin to use to then empty the cart, but its not very good as customers have to click a link in order to redirect.

So should i empty it when they click the checkout button just before the dynamic button?

I can also use these setting in php to prevent cach back button issues

```
// Date in the past
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
// Always modified
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
// HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
// HTTP/1.0
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

What would to guys recommend?

cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you've updated/inserted to the database.

This is because if they go back and add more products, it'll have duplicate entries, and you don't want that.

as soon as you do your database inserting, and `header()` them off to Paypal etc, clear their cart.

Comment: heres how the cart works: cart checkout > 'header()' redirect to paypal button > paypal site. So i have 2 option 1. empty cart after cart checkout before 'header()' redirect or leave it and hope they use the return url .. is there away to do this clear cart with IPN?

Comment: empty the cart just before the header. Unfortunately users will do whatever they want to, so you need to make sure they're being handled however you want. On one site I have had a button for "restore your cart?", when their payment had not gone through, by temporarily saving their cart to another location, and clearing their main cart.

Comment: Hay Jared thats not a bad idea about the "restore your cart?" option..im gonna have a good think about that and see how i can implement it great idea! thanks Jared

Comment: all good mate. My method was `$_SESSION['cart']` was the cart, and when they go to paypal, I move `$_SESSION['cart']` to `$_SESSION['temp']['cart']`, and if they click the "restore cart" button, it will just move it back. Good luck buddy.

Comment: For some bizzare reason im unable to use SESSIONS :( my website is available with and without the www prefix a and sessions created with the www prefix will not be available without which has been driving me crazy since i started this script. I was forcedto switch to cookies and even with cookies im forced to add the domain otherwise i have the same problem. I've even tried `session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com'); session_start();`
' but this does not work so i gave up on SESSION. I do prefer sessions then cookies as you cant set arrays in cookies like you can with sessions

Comment: alrighty well if there's no way that you can switch to be able to use `$_SESSION`, I would still use the same method but saving the arrays serialized to cookies (means they're a string). Just means calling `serialize()` and `unserialize()` when inserting/grabbing from cookies.

Comment: Hi Jared i gave the sessions annother go today and i managed to get them working across my entire domain. I had to enter the following code to the top of every page: `$some_name = session_name("domain");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.mydomain.com');
session_start();` i have now re-written the script to use sessions which is so much better as i dont have to save loads of info on the server :) all i have left ot do now is the restore cart option and jobs a good'un thansk for that advise totally solved my original problem :)

Comment: All good mate! remember to vote up so that the Question says answered. If you need help shoot me a PM, more than happy to help. :)

Comment: ah m8 this works great thanks to sessions! the restore cart works perfect.. just out of interest what does the temp part do in $_SESSION['temp']['cart'] cheers

Comment: all good mate. it's just an **array inside an array**. For example I'd use `$_SESSION['temp']['errors']`, `$_SESSION['temp']['user']`, etc. Really up to you. Something like `$_SESSION['cart_old']` might be more appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 0):

From [Paypal website](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf): 
*With Auto Return for PayPal Payments Standard, **you can avoid making people click a button
to return to your website** after they complete their payments with PayPal...
...
NOTE: If you have turned on Auto Return and have chosen to turn on PayPal Account
Optional for new users, a new user will not be automatically directed back to your
website, but will be given the option to return.*

Meaning, if you want to auto-redirect to work without the user clicking a link/button, you should disable the option: `PayPal Account Optional for new users`

Comment: oh wait - would this mean that all customer MUST have a paypal account?

Comment: depends on how your database is set up. if you're explicitly only using paypal, then yes. This will require you to have a field in the database that is the payment status. defaulted to `Pending`, and if they come back from the Paypal page successfully, it's changed to `Complete`.

Comment: OK then - ill have to give that option a miss thenas i dont want to force customer to have a paypal account. cheers alf!